# Extract and compare text from an image with a baseline text string in TestComplete

Tags: automation, testcomplete

I have a scenario in which user enters text in a text box .
Now, when the workflow of the test case is executed,the user provided text appears in an image format after the test flow is fully executed.

This is actually how the application under test treats the input data.It represents the text in a non-editable format.I simply take the snapshot here for comparison purpose .i.e setting the baseline for my test.

Is there a way that I can store this user entered text in step 1 in my baseline data store and then extract the text from image as part of validation of the correct data provided by user in the test case conclusion step.﻿

I have used two checkpoints strategies to find the right solution,just am not sure whether it actually serves the purpose.

1.Added Object checkpoint while script record ,here's the script

Call Objects.configPackage_success.Check(Aliases.Microsoft_ConfigurationManagement.SmsWizardForm.zpagePanel.zinteriorPagePanel.WizardPage.ActionsCompletionWizardPageControl.labelCaption)

I have enabled the text field for this property during record time.I hope it compares the text extracted from the object somehow.I maybe wrong.

2.Added Property checkpoint with script below

Call aqObject.CheckProperty(Aliases.Microsoft_ConfigurationManagement.SmsWizardForm.zpagePanel.zinteriorPagePanel.WizardPage.ActionsCompletionWizardPageControl.labelCaption.Text, "OleValue", cmpEqual, "The Create Package and Program Wizard completed successfully")

Again,it hopefully does the text comparison part.Not sure how it internally works.

Or do I have rely only on Region checkpoints for validation of my test-output with baseline image.

Thanks

Comment: So, you need to programmatically read and validate some text displayed in your application as image in order to be unreadable programmatically. Right? I suspect that this is hardly possible. However, can you provide with more info? Why the app renders text as image? Is the text available via a property of the control that displays this image? Can you post here an image to demonstrate how this control looks like?

Comment: You can try the OCR functionality of TestComplete. If it does not work for you, I recommend you contacting the SmartBear Support team: http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete

Comment: yes I need to programmatically verify this.I'm afraid I can't post pics (low rep.).I just checked again.the text is available for the user input data.but there would be a challenge to focus on the particular object the next time application is launched.I've no idea how to do that.Probably, I'll need to find a way to recognize what user provided as an input ,then convert that text/string and compare and verify the target object.